# Status returned by url [http://localhost:9000/batch_bootstrap/index] is not valid

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

When I am trying to run sonar-scanner, I was not able to start sonarqube and this error is being displayed.

INFO: Scanner configuration file: /sonar-scanner-2.8/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.8
INFO: Java 1.8.0_91 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Mac OS X 10.12.1 x86_64
INFO: User cache: /.sonar/cache
ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 0.417s
INFO: Final Memory: 3M/123M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:84)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:71)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:67)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:218)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:156)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:72)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to download libraries from server
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:93)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.download(Jars.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.JarDownloader.download(JarDownloader.java:39)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory$1.run(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:75)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Status returned by url [http://localhost:9000/batch_bootstrap/index] is not valid: [404]
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.callUrl(ServerConnection.java:115)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ServerConnection.downloadString(ServerConnection.java:98)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.Jars.downloadFiles(Jars.java:78)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you should first start SonarQube. When it runs, then you can start your scanner.

I get the case where my port 9001 was already in used and SonarQube server did't start. To resolve it, I changed the port to 19001 (free on my computer) in  *SonarQube_Dir/conf/sonar.properties*

```
sonar.search.port=19001
```

After this change, I was able to start the sonarQube server, and run the scanner.

Comment: Hi Loic, Sorry for the confusion. I have started the server and then ran scanner. I meant to say that on running the scanner I am not able to access the URL.

Comment: Can you access the SonarQube admin page at http://localhost:9000 ? If not, it is likely that your port (or an other you need) is already used. Have a look in the SonarQube server logs.

Comment: No I am not able to access admin page. These are the ports that are being used in my machine.Port Scan has started…

Port Scanning host: 127.0.0.1

  Open TCP Port:  1111     lmsocialserver
  Open TCP Port:  2222     rockwell-csp2
  Open TCP Port:  3141     vmodem
  Open TCP Port:  5432     postgresql
  Open TCP Port:  9001     etlservicemgr
Port Scan has completed…

Comment: Hi sandreep, I edited my answer with the change of port 9001. It seams you are facing the same issue and I hope you'll be able to start your SonarQube server and your scanner with the configuration.